# unnecessary movements in my a-star implementation

Tags: path-finding, a-star

I've made an a-star implementation with euclidean heuristics, and it works, but makes unnecessary movements in some situations.

Here is the screenshot:
http://clip2net.com/s/6v2iU4

Path starts on the blue circle and, in theory, cell to the right of it has less F (movement cost + heuristic cost), so a-star takes it first, but it ends up in building not the shortest path.

How can i fix this? 
Or a-star is supposed to work this way and i dont need to do anything?

My code: http://pastebin.com/02u33jY6 (h + cpp)

Comment: There is either a bug in your code, or your heuristic is incorrect (A* may return incorrect paths if the heuristic over-evaluate the distance of the path). We cannot say what is the issue without seeing the code.

Comment: Did you forget to change the parent of a node to which you find a better path?

Comment: ok, ill continue to search for bug in my code, also iv added a link to the code. and yes, im (at least i think so) updating parents

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your algorithm is, your implementation returns the path, when it finds the destination in your `openList`.

The A* should terminate when destination node is in the `closedList`, not in the open list.

```
// check if there is dst node on the closed list
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < closedList.size(); i++ )
{
    if ( closedList.at( i ).getIndex() == dstTileIndex )
    {
        GSPathFinderNode* backtrackNode = &closedList.at( i );
        resultPathNodes->insert( resultPathNodes->begin(), GSCommonMapNode( backtrackNode->getIndex(),
                                                                           backtrackNode->getPosX(),
                                                                           backtrackNode->getPosY() ) );

        while ( 1 )
        {
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < closedList.size(); j++ )
            {
                if ( closedList.at( j ).getIndex() == backtrackNode->getParentNodeIndex() )
                {
                    backtrackNode = &closedList.at( j );
                    resultPathNodes->insert( resultPathNodes->begin(), GSCommonMapNode( backtrackNode->getIndex(),
                                                                                       backtrackNode->getPosX(),
                                                                                       backtrackNode->getPosY() ) );

                    if ( backtrackNode->getIndex() == srcTileIndex )
                        return true; // success
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that could only affect end of the path, and i have problems in the beginning. It seems that part of my code that should update parents to better path just don't work )) iv placed a breakpoint there and it didn't stopped

Comment: iv found where my problem was: i totally misunderstood idea of G cost. )))